# Scrapy Xpath: when I select the <td><12</td>, I get" <td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>" instead of "<12"

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

The html code is like

```
<td><12</td>
```

And i wanna to get the "<12", but when I use "select('td/text()').extract()", I get "[u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']".

Every items contain "<" are all like this. How can I get the "<12"? Thanks!

Comment: It's invalid HTML. Are you using `HtmlXPathSelector`?

Comment: yap.I use HtmlXPathSelector, but It's not my site. what I do is just get the content.

Comment: Do you have lxml installed?

Comment: @Blender yes. Maybe I should convert "<" to "&lt;" first.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing `<12` in the HTML, type `&lt;12`. That should render and parse properly.

The explanation is that HTML considers `<` to be a tag opener, and so it confuses him. For that reason, you need to use a process called 'escaping', which means you convert all your special characters to normal "escape symbols", which your browser (or whatever is reading your HTML) should recognize.

A quick google search gives a list of those [here](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php).

Comment: If OP is scraping the data, I doubt he has control over the HTML.

Comment: Whoops, my bad then. Shame on whoever wrote that website :) At any rate, this sounds like a mismatch between scrapy and browsers - since browsers are designed to be robust and try to accept things like `<12`, and its possible scrapy wasn't designed to deal with this case. I wouldn't go as far as calling it a bug (neither in the browsers nor in scrapy), but an annoying mismatch of behaviors. That being said, I don't know how you should go about solving that, except maybe use something else to extract the data (possibly not scrapy at all). Good luck :)

Comment: Really poor code. But actually he had did it, I really have no idea how to solve it.